# ema5 ema21 ta lib not matching with tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api, pandas-ta

I tried below code

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_ta as ta

dfpl = yf.download('TCS.NS',start='2023-01-01',end='2023-01-05',interval='15m')

dfpl["EMA5"] = ta.ema(dfpl["Close"],5)
dfpl["EMA21"] = ta.ema(dfpl["Close"],21)

print(dfpl[20:])
```

It gave me these values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxawX.png)

Tradingview values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8nHO.png)

Tradinview settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9KBv.png)

What wrong I'm doing here ?